# how to create new table with left join

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to create a new table call checkdownload and get data from two table which is student and downlaod table.

```
   table student

    --------------------------------------------------
    | studentId | username | password | email | name |
    --------------------------------------------------

       table downlaod
    ------------------------------------
    | ID| studentId | downloadId | Name | 
    ------------------------------------
```

```
     $sql2="select id from upload";
                $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
                while($rows2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    $id5=$rows2['id'];

        $sql3 = "create table checkdownload(SELECT student.studentId, student.name, downlaod.downlaodId, downlaod.Name FROM student as student LEFT JOIN downlaod as downlaod ON student.studentId = downlaod.studentId WHERE downlaod.downlaodId =$id5)";

                    $result3=mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
}
```

Comment: `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT....`

Comment: You have `downlaod.downlaodId` yet you state your column is called `downloadId`. Very much a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE table checkdownload as (SELECT s.studentId, s.name, d.downlaodId, d.Name FROM student s LEFT JOIN downlaod d ON s.studentId = d.studentId WHERE d.downlaodId =$id5)
```

if ur query is ok this will create table with structure and all values. if you want only structure without values then add at last `and 1=2`